# Get random element from list (in other file)

Tags: python, discord.py

(sorry for my english :V)
I am making a discord bot with discord.py.

```
import random
class List():
    list = [
        "very"
        "big"
        "list"
         ]
    def choice(self, list):
        result = random.choice(list)
        return result
```

This isn't that list (its very big). I have to choice random element from thi list.

```
import List
list = List
@bot.command
async def send(ctx):
    element = list.choice(list)
    ctx.send(element)
```

buuuut it raises an exception:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
ctx.send(element)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: `list = List` binds a new name to `List`. if you want an instance you need `list = List()`. On the other hand your variable shouldn't be called `list` because it overwrites the built in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). `import List` suggests, that your class definition is in a module called `List.py`. In that case you need `my_list = List.List()`

Comment: In your `choice` method you want `result = random.choice(self.list)`. Of course using a better name than `list` still applies.

Comment: You need to use `await ctx.send(element)`

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.send` is a coroutine and not a regular function, you need to await on it.
so: `await ctx.send(...)` is the right syntax